# What is the difference between an academic CV in the US and an academic CV in France?

Tags: united-states, cv, france

I am currently applying for graduate school in France. How (if at all) would I modify my existing CV in the standard US format to conform to French academic standards?

I have searched online, but most results are comparing a standard US resume to a European CV.

Comment: Maybe translate it to French?

Comment: @AzorAhai probably not a good idea if he's looking for a PhD (unless maybe in some specific field)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head: The European CVs I've seen typically include a photograph of the person; that is more the exception than the rule in US-style CVs.